# Is contractor the one who employs someone or the one who's employed?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

I've always used the term *contractor* to describe the type of engagement I have towards my clients. Basically, it mean that I'm not a permanent employee but rather a temporarily hired expert with the aim of delivering a specialized service. Basically a temp but with highly specific skill set.

Today, I've read [an article](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-cleverest-scams-you-have-come-across) that used the term *contractor* in the opposite sense. The contractor in this sense is the one that is asking someone to do something, not the one being asked.

> ... risk it too much. So he asked his **contractors** to give him several days for preparations. And he ...

Once I started thinking about it, it hit me that the (to me) unusual application of the term actually makes a lot more sense. If A proposes a contract and B accespts it, then A has contracted B, making A a *contractor* and B a *contractee* (just like A would be an *employer* and B an *employee*).

How should we treat the term in question? Have I been a *contractee* unawarely?

Comment: The Russian author of the article used the word incorrectly. See [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/contractor). The contractor is the person who is given the contract to do the work.,

Comment: Originally, "contractor" simply meant *One who enters into a contract or agreement; a contracting party*. So that could be *either* side of an arrangement as described above. But that definition, which is sense #1 from the full Oxford English Dictionary, is flagged "**Obsolete except as in sense #2**", where sense #2 is defined as *One who contracts or undertakes to supply certain articles, or to perform any work or service (esp. for government or other public body), at a certain price or rate; in the building and related trades, one who is prepared to undertake work by contract.*

Comment: @KateBunting All right, so I've been using *contractor* to describe the kind of engagement correctly. Now, that said, what do you think of the *contractor* / *employer* versus *contractee* / *employee*? Doesn't it make a lot of sense (despite being incorrect)?

Comment: I wouldn't have known that _contractee_ was even a word (my spellchecker doesn't recognise it), but [apparently it is](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contractee). If someone has given you the contract to do a job you are the contractor.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a mistake, so there's nothing to learn from it

Comment: @gotube the fact that it is a mistake *is* something to be learned! 

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that’s an excellent answer. Why not make it so?

Comment: @gotube I disagree that a mistake being the base of a question qualifies it for closing. Many questions come up because of that. Also, in this particular case, I learned something (and apparently others did too). Are you saying that the question is poorly formulated? Or is the issue that it's simply too issue and uninteresting?

Comment: @tkp: I added the comment while closevoting. I figured OP could easily look in any number of online dictionaries to see that ***contractor*** today always means the *"**hiree**"*, not the *"**hirer**"*. I just thought I'd add that background about obsolete usages to imply that OP had reasonable "justification" for his uncertainty - I would certainly never *downvote* such a question, but I'm not convinced it merits a lot of attention for the benefit of future visitors to the site.

Comment: @KonradViltersten There are an infinite number of ways to make a mistake in a language. This site is not a catalogue of possible mistakes. Questions and answers here should be about things that other users are likely to gain benefit from down the road. A question about the misuse of a term cannot have a useful answer because language learners aren't likely to ever come across that exact mistake again. Questions are regularly closed here for this reason. To be clear, I think it was the right thing to ask, but now that we know the original was an error, we should close it

Comment: @gotube I agree with your point. However, I'd like to be less restrictive with the range of mistakes being basis to closing. In this particular case, which I realize isn't sufficiently apparent, the actual question regards the meaning of *contractor* vs *contractee*. That's not a mistake as such but rather a product of reasoning around the language. (I anticipated curiosity about a reference and source of such unusual idea. Hence the link. It got undeservedly much fokus.) Admittedly, there **is** something as *contractee* and it does beg the question. Perhaps I should reformulate the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stolen from FumbleFingers's comment:

Originally, "contractor" simply meant One who enters into a contract or agreement; a contracting party. So that could be either side of an arrangement as described above. But that definition, which is sense #1 from the full Oxford English Dictionary, is flagged "Obsolete except as in sense #2", where sense #2 is defined as One who contracts or undertakes to supply certain articles, or to perform any work or service (esp. for government or other public body), at a certain price or rate; in the building and related trades, one who is prepared to undertake work by contract.